# Setting environment for AngularJS development with existing OSGi/Rest serverices

Tags: angularjs, node.js, rest

How to setup the dev environment where the UI is to be re-done using AngularJS and typescript etc but we already have an existing set of services hosted in rest/osgi bundles.

All the development models with AngularJS and type script talks about node/npm etc but how do we hit existing services with that? do i need to enable cors etc for development? 
how is UI development done in these kind of projects as i believe not all projects are done from the beginning and have liberty to use node at server.

Answer (score 0):

Well, usually from an angular app you define some kind of angular service that talks to your api in a standard way.

It's true that most "Frontend" projects use a mocking server during development but it isn't hard to hard to use a real server for this, provided it's not you own production server, obviously.

About the cors issue, I use to let CORS fully open during development ,and have a minimally accesable configuration on production, depending on your project.

Comment: can you please elaborate on "but it isn't hard to hard to use a real server for this, provided it's not you own production server" - that's precisely what i want to do,  how is it possible to use my own real server (non production) with angular/typescript UI  (using node) without enabling cors?

Comment: 1st 'HARD to HARD' its a typo :). Anyway using a non production server it's easy to install node there ( preferably non root) and make it listen on non-used high port ( as 3000). As it is a non production server, and hopefully only accesable from your internall network, and is it a temporary setup, i cannot see any security risk in let the CORS configuration fuly open

Answer (score 0):

After some research we have finalized the *DevEnv* and it's working out very well.

1. used angular cli for development
2. used proxy server to make the calls made to 4200 port to redirect to express server running at port 3000

`package.json`:

```
"start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
```

3. finally wrote a small express server to login to existing server and then pipe all requests!

This was our code:

```
var app = express();
//enable cors    
var cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors());

//relay all calls to osgi server!!
app.use('/a/b/c/rest', function (req, res) {
  var apiServerHost = "https://" + HOST + ":" + PORT + "/a/b/c/rest";

  try {
    var url = apiServerHost + req.url;
    req.pipe(request(
      {
        headers: headers,
        url: url,
        "rejectUnauthorized": false
      })).pipe(res);

  } catch (error) 
  {
    console.log("Error " + error);
  }
}       // Added by review
```

No mock required